# Close all accordion on mouseout event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I close all accordion contents on **mouseout** event?
Here's my Jquery code:

```
$(function() {

        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            header: "h3", 
            active: false, 
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content" 
        });
  });
```

Where can i place the onmouseout function to close all my contents?

Comment: Did you try `$( "#accordion" ).mouseout(...)` ?

Comment: yes but it doesn't close also

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the mouseout function like this:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  header: "h3", 
  active: false, 
  collapsible: true,
  heightStyle: "content" 
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).accordion('active', false);
});
```

The jQuery [accordion documention](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) says "Setting active to false will collapse all panels."

Answer (score 1):

To close a complete accordion you have to set the `active` option to `false`:

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ active: false });
// or
$("#accordion").accordion( "option", "active", false);
```

As you can see in the <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5j9Y/)</kbd> the following code works as desired:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "h3",
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content"
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).accordion({
        active: false
    });
});
```